# Could not find where is the source code of the language in a Login.apsx

Tags: asp.net

I have a file called Login.aspx

In the end of the code i have 3 flag so i could change the language.

Code is:

```
<ams:AMSImageButton ID="btnEnglishUnitedStates" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/images/flags/us.gif" onclick="SetLanguage" CommandArgument="en-US" ResourceID="99999" Resource="Content" ResourceName="LANGUAGE_ENGLISH" />
<ams:AMSImageButton ID="btnFrenchCanadian" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/images/flags/fr.gif" onclick="SetLanguage" CommandArgument="fr-CA" ResourceID="99999" Resource="Content" ResourceName="LANGUAGE_FRENCH" />
<ams:AMSImageButton ID="btnSpanishInternational" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/images/flags/es.gif" onclick="SetLanguage" CommandArgument="es-ES" ResourceID="99999" Resource="Content" ResourceName="LANGUAGE_SPANISH" />
```

How to find the location/source code of those languages? so i can can change something.

Thank You

Comment: Is there inside the project a user control with code behind like AmsImageButton.ascx.cs ?

Comment: The idea its not a project it is exported.

Comment: Agree with @AlkisGiamalis.  Also search your solution for SetLanguage, as it's being called on the click.  It may lead you to the rest of the code you are looking for.

Comment: resource manager: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks